# Sprite-Kit Error

Tags: ios, swift

Im following a tutorial right now and Im getting an error that I do not know how to fix.

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit

class GameViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let scene = StartGameScene(size: view.bounds.size)
    let skView = view as! SKView
    skView.showsFPS = true
    skView.showsNodeCount = true
    skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
    scene.scaleMode = .ResizeFill
    skView.presentScene(scene)
}

override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
    return true
}
}
```

On line 8 the `let scene = StartGameScene(size: view.bounds.size)`
is giving me an error:

> use of Unresolved Identifier ' StartGameScene'.

I have created a CocoaTouch class and named `StartGameScene`. I dont know what the issue is. How do I fix it?

Comment: I don't see a class named StartGameScene. Maybe you should include that code in your post? If its objective-c then you would need to make sure its imported but otherwise its probably just a typo.

Answer (score 1):

StartGameScene would need to be a class declared like this:

```
class StartGameScene: SKScene {...}
```

Either StartGameScene is not declared as an SKScene or the class itself is not declared.

Answer (score 0):

The cocoa touch class that you have created has to inherit from SKScene. SKScene is the class in which you define your game's scene. Hence your code should look like:

class StartGameScene: SKScene {

}

If you have already done this, then please make sure there isn't any typographic error.

Answer (score 0):

just change `StartGameScene` to `GameScene`